# How to recode numerical to categorical data

Tags: python, col

I am new to Python, I am studying it for data science purposes. Right now, I am trying to recode some numerical data (1,2,3 etc) into categories. It requires a little loop in the end, but I can't get that right. It causes a key error 3.

The dataset has 21 columns.

Can anyone help?
Thanks!!

```
for col_dic in code_list:
col = col_dic[0]
dic = col_dic[1]
values[col] = [dic[x] for x in values[col]]
```

Comment: Can you show some example input data and expected output ? See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, some of it is this:      
            ['property_type',
            {'1' : 'One to four-family',
             '2' : 'Manufactured housing',
             '3' : 'Multifamily'}],
            ['loan_purpose',
            {'1' : 'Home purchase',
             '2' : 'Home improvement',
             '3' : 'Refinancing'}],

for col_dic in code_list:
    col = col_dic[0]
    dic = col_dic[1]
    values[col] = [dic[x] for x in values[col]]

Comment: Sorry, i can't get it indented properly! Anyway, the expected output is that the numbers in the columns are replaced by the letters. It seems to work, except for that loop in the end.

Comment: The error I am getting is this: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bce89ead0996> in <module>
     46     col = col_dic[0]
     47     dic = col_dic[1]
---> 48     values[col] = [dic[x] for x in values[col]]
     49 
     50 values.head()

<ipython-input-6-bce89ead0996> in <listcomp>(.0)
     46     col = col_dic[0]
     47     dic = col_dic[1]
---> 48     values[col] = [dic[x] for x in values[col]]
     49 
     50 values.head()

KeyError: 3

Answer (score 0):

It is rather hard to understand what exactly you want to see in result, but the cause of this error is clear:

You are iterating through a list of lists. Every `col_dic` contains a `col = col_dic[0]` (string like `'property_type'`) and `dic = col_dic[1]` (dictionary). In the last line you are writing info to a `values` dict (I suppose you created it before). This error is appearing because `dic` doesn't contain a particular key from the `values[col]`. For example:

`values[col]` is equal to `{1: [], 2: [], 3: []}` and `dic` is equal to `{1: 'One', 2: 'Two'}`. When you are iterating through `values[col]`, you are trying to find a key `3` in `dic`. But it contains no `3` key, so the error is appearing. You should check that `dic` contains this key like this:

```
values_list = []
for v in values[col]:
    if v in dic:
        values_list.append(dic[v])
values[col] = values_list
```

Also note that your keys are strings represents integers. Your error can appear when you try to find a key `'3'` (string) in a dict contains keys like `3` (integers). So I suggest you to convert your keys to strings: `str(key)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me on the way to solving it!

Comment: I will ask a more detailed question next time, by the way!